# Array representation of linked lists

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, linked-list

I am reading Algorithms in C++ book by Robert Sedgwick. It was mentioned that linked lists can be represented by arrays. Can any one show the simple implementation of linked lists using arrays ?

Is it possible to implement Josephous problem using array implementation of linked lists ? If possible a sample implementation would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Instead of a pointer or reference to the next element of the linked list, record the index in the array of the next element. Use an index that cannot possibly be an array index (e.g. -1) to indicate the end of the list.

Given you're asking then for a solution to a well-known and much solved problem, I'll assume it's an assignment and leave the solution to the reader :)

Comment: It is not an excesive, i am self reading the book and got the question, and trying to get help here. Thanks

Comment: OK. Solving the problem yourself willl teach you more than getting a solution here. Have a go, and update your question if you get stuck?

Comment: I see.  Does that mean you could potentially make what node structure out of the array like a higherarchy?